# Changing color of Ogre manual objects

Tags: ogre

I am working on visualizing different objects in Rviz using Ogre::ManualObjects and Ogre::BillBoardSet.

After the elements are drawn, the user is given option to configure color of each objects during run-time.

What is the best way to change color? Because there is no built-in API to set color in Ogre.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you think there is no built-in API for this?
[`Ogre::Billboard::setColour`](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_billboard.html#a9126c29605e55b8bdb5f81adf267259a) and [`Ogre::ManualObject::colour`](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_manual_object.html#a790bf1eacf2c1c07bd663891fb6df39b) are available! If you post some real code here, we could help you use them

Comment: My question is to change color of Ogre::ManualObject which is already drawn using a color. To do this I have to use beginUpdate(), then change color using Ogre::ManualObject::colour. Is there any API like Ogre::ManualObject::setColor() ?

Comment: no, you have to deal with manual objects just like you described: update per vertex

Comment: or you still have the option of using materials (`setMaterialName`) and provide some pre-defined ones to your users to chose from

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer. I will go with solution of updating per vertex. That will serve my purpose efficiently.